# NDK r10b 32 and 64 bit builder for mac

Tags: android, macos, android-ndk, 32bit-64bit, ndk-build

Here is the link to 32 bit NDK r10b builder

http://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk32-r10b-darwin-x86_64.tar.bz2

Here is the link to 64 bit NDK r10b builder

http://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk32-r10b-darwin-x86_64.tar.bz2

Both the NDK builder seems to be identical and both are marked as **r10b (64-bit)** in RELEASE.TXT

[image]

So, Am I doing downloading NDK builders from wrong place ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The Android NDK is located here:** https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html

Make sure you are using the latest NDK, you have `r10b` when there is a `r10d`. Also, they may have simply forgotten to update the `RELEASE.TXT`.

**For Mac x86 - 32bit:**

http://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r10d-darwin-x86.bin

**For Mac x86_64 - 64bit:**

http://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r10d-darwin-x86_64.bin

Comment: Do you think version r10b and r10d will compile the same native libraries in different way ?The library which I am using is compiled by r10b and I am just worried r10d compilation might cause some trouble.What's your take on this ?

Comment: No, you should always use the latest NDK just like you should always compile with the latest SDK.

Comment: I am yet to try..Anyway congrats on your 10K Cheers !

Comment: @Shajo o wow! thanks! Let me know if you run into anymore NDK issues.

Comment: It turns out you can have problems with newer versions, see e.g. https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-js/issues/902 .

Comment: @JaakL Ok. Was this documented anywhere? It would be nice to know what has been "removed".